# Indexing options are not showing up in sitecore control panel (v8.2 update 3) and developer tab is not visible

Tags: upgrade, indexing

We are in the process of upgrading sitecore website from v7.2 to v8.2 and are not seeing the indexing manager links in sitecore control panel and Developer tab is also not showing up within content editor with builtin admin account login.

Comment: For the developer tab to show up you need to right click on the ribbon and select the developer from the list. It is hidden by default. About the link for the index manager, you mean the link to open the modal is not appearing or the indexes that you want to rebuild are not appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sitecore Developer Tab**

By default, Sitecore hides the Developer Tab. In order to active the Developer Tab, you need to right click on the Content Editor Ribbon and select the Developer option from the list. Please see below screenshot.

[image]

**Sitecore Index Manager Link**

It may be that when upgrading to Sitecore 8.2 from 7.2, some items were not properly installed or have been missed.

- Make sure that you have the `Indexing Manager` item under the path `/sitecore/content/Applications/Control Panel/Indexing/Indexing Manager` in the **Core Database**.
- Make sure that the field `Click` is populated with the value `indexing:runmanager`.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Note that the index configuration has changed in Sitecore 8.2. In the different indexes (core, master and web), it makes use of the following configuration:

```
<configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration" />
```

And you need to make sure that all your custom indexes have this configuration. Moreover, the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` should be something as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Hishaam for that method of bringing back the developer tab in 8.2. We tried with plain vanilla sitecore 8.2 update 3 core database and the upgraded core database. both had the indexing manager configuration as you described. but indexing options are not available in control panel and In the content editor ribbon, 'Rebuild All' button is showing the message - "Indexes Gallery failed to render index list'

Comment: So, you have an error in your indexes. The type is not correct

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: Also please check the logs and share it

Comment: @vijaymajeti I will suggest to take a backup of your existing upgraded website and then replace your search config files with Vanila Sitecore 8.2 update 3 config files. It looks like there is some Search index config file error.

Comment: Thank you @HishaamNamooya regarding the developer tab. And, Extraneous character in one of the config file has caused indexing manager options to not show up. Now, it all works as expected.